# Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[String]' Swift 2

Tags: swift2

I try to updating my project from Swift to Swift 2 but I get an error with the following code:

```
let PhotoController = UIImagePickerController() 
        PhotoController.delegate = self
        PhotoController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera 

        let mediaTypes:[AnyObject] = [kUTTypeImage] 

        PhotoController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes 

        PhotoController.allowsEditing  = false

        self.presentViewController(PhotoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On the following line:

```
PhotoController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
```

the compiler indicate this error:

> cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[String]'

Can you help me please ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sure that the array is of type `[String]` you can make a forced cast:

```
PhotoController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes as! [String]
```

Otherwise I would suggest to use flatMap and an individual optional cast of each object:

```
PhotoController.mediaTypes = mediaTypes.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my guess, but judging on documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes

inspite of the fact that mediaTypes is [AnyObject] Apple guys in their example casting it to [String] (example on Obj-c!)

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

So I would cast to String